# Trying to retrieve file by GM_xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, blob, greasemonkey

I wrote a script run on TamperMonkey to download mp3 from streetvoice.com.

The download works, but the size of download is larger than the size it should be, and even couldn't  play by any player.

What's the bug in my script?

```
$.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:queryurl,
            async:"True",
            success:function(data){
                var downloadUrl = data.file;
                GM_xmlhttpRequest({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: downloadUrl,
                    responseType:"blob",
                    onload: function(r) {
                        alert(downloadUrl);
                        //alert(r.responseText);
                        var bb = new Blob([r], {type: "audio/mp3"});
                        saveAs(bb, data.name+".mp3");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

For copyright reason, I have corrected and deleted some parts of code.

Comment: If you use Tampermonkey, it has GM_download

Comment: BTW, `responsetype` should be `responseType`.

Comment: Well, it works, thank you very much.

Comment: I still wonder why the download fails by using GM_xmlhttprequest.

Comment: @wOxxOm  what's the problem of GM_xmlhttprequest